# Any way to check nested object nullability in Java

Tags: java, java-8

Is there any way to write the following in Java?

```
abc.getXyz() == null ? null : abc.getXyz().getWer();
```

Comment: other than the one that you are showing you mean?

Comment: You mean a better way? If so, what are you looking to improve on?

Comment: The code line you provided, is in Java. A [Ternary Operator](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/ternary-operator.html) is used in that line.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [safe navigation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator), which Java does not have.

Comment: You could employ an Optional in your classes. Or you might be able to use something like `Objects.requireNonNull(abc.getXyz()).getWer();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Optional`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(abc)
    .map(p -> p.getXyz())
    .map(p -> p.getWer())
    .ifPresentOrElse(
        p -> System.out.println(p),
        () -> System.out.println(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

A more readable one :

```
return Objects.isNull(abc.getXyz()) ? null:abc.getXyz().getWer();
```

if using java8 you can use below with optional

```
return Optional.ofNullable(abc.getXyz()).map(Obj::abc.getXyz()).orElse(null);
```

Comment: `Obj::abc.getXyz()` is not valid syntax. Did you mean `Obj::getWer` instead? (where `Obj` is the type returned by `getXyz()`)